# Turn number in array to stars

Tags: c, arrays

I hope someone can help me.
I want to create stars "*" instead of my numbers in the output of array, 10 numbers.

Example

Input
Number 1: 3
Number 2: 2
Number 10: 5

Output
Number 1: ***
Number 2: **
Number 10: *****

But i get always the same number of stars.
Thanks! Dear Harman

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int tal[10], i, j, z;

    printf("Mata in tio tal mellan 0 och 60:\n");
    for(z=0;z<10;z++)
    {
        printf("Tal %d: ", z+1);
        scanf("%d",&tal[i]);
    }


printf("\nRita ut stapeldiagram:\n");
for(z=0;z<10;z++)
{
    printf("Tal %d: ", z + 1);

    for (j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't edit your code based on answers people give.  It invalidates the answers and comments given.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your bug. Your inner for-loop that prints a star is redefining the iteration index, `i`.  Simple fix is to use a new variable, say `j`, in this line:

```
for (i=0; i<tal; i++)
```

To this:

```
for (int j=0; j<tal; j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when scanning user input you are storing the value at the same position of the array `tal` . Increment the value of `i` so that in every iteration the new value takes a new memory place .

```
for(z=0, i=0; z<10; z++, i++)
{
    printf("Tal %d: ", z+1);
    scanf("%d",&tal[i]);
}
```

Secondly when printing out the stars in the inner loop, you are iterating to a fixed number `i` . So , it is printing the fixed number of stars in every iteration of outer loop. Iterate the inner loop to `tal[z]` . I hope this will make you smile .

```
for(z=0;z<10;z++)
{
 printf("Tal %d: ", z + 1);

 for (j=0; j<tal[z]; j++)
  {
    printf("*");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```